# Adding Dynamic Content inside <ng-template>

Tags: angular, ng-template, ng-content, ng-container, ngtemplateoutlet

```
 <ng-template #reuse>
  <div>Hello World</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reuse"></ng-container>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reuse">
  <p>Good Morning</p>
</ng-container>
```

I would like to reuse the **reuse** template reference multiple times but with small modifications each time.
In the above example, in the 2nd `<ng-container>` I would also like to add an additional `<p>` tag after the `<div>` tag (in the `<ng-template>`). Is it possible to achieve that without creating another template?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pass a context object to your template with `[ngTemplateOutletContext]` or the shorthand with `*ngTemplateOutlet`. Then you can render things based on that context.

```js
<ng-template #reuse let-message="message">
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <p *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reuse"></ng-container>

<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="reuse"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ message: 'Good Morning' }"
></ng-container>
```

or

```html
<ng-template #reuse let-message="message">
  <div>Hello World</div>
  <p *ngIf="message">{{ message }}</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="reuse"></ng-container>

<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="reuse; context: { message: 'Good Morning' }"
></ng-container>
```

Doc reference: https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: I have multiple sections in a component with multiple lines of repeating html code. So i have grouped the common code into an <ng-template> for reuse. In certain sections I have a button or few div tags that dont appear in other sections. As you have mentioned I can use the context to differentiate between the sections and then add the non-common HTML code using an ng-if condition.

Comment: what if 'Good Morning' itself is a variable, which changes, based for example on the time of day.  *ngTemplateOutlet="reuse; context: { message: timeOfDayGreeting }" >>> timeOfDayGreeting doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @alex351 seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1mnmd?file=src/main.ts. Although if you want a UI rerender at a certain time of day you need to schedule it somehow. Angular isn't going to recheck all your UI conditions every second.

Comment: @alex351 ie. you should be changing a component property with a `setTimeout` rather than using an if condition to calculate the message.

Answer (score 0):

What is the end goal here? When or how happens this "each time"? `ng-template` is never generated in html code, it generates it's contents as html at run time. So adding new html lines to a template is not possible. It is a dynamic abstraction of Angular syntax.

However you could use template variables to pre-configure the template to add new lines when themplate bound variables change.

For example, you could add more template variables by adding `let` to `ng-template`. https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-input-variable

```html
<div *ngFor="let day of Weekdays"> 
<ng-container *ngIf = 
    "(day == 'Saturday' || day == 'Sunday'); else elseTemplate"> 
  <h1>{{day}} is a weekend</h1> 
</ng-container> 
<ng-template #elseTemplate> 
  <h1>{{day}} is not a weekend</h1> 
</ng-template> 
</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  Weekdays: Array = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
  ];
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-ng-template-and-ng-container-exam-w2zn1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The scenario is that there are multiple lines of html code repeating in multiple sections in component. So i have grouped the common code into an <ng-template> for reuse. In certain sections I have a button or few div tags that dont appear in other sections. I just required a solution how I could add these buttons or div elements in the existing <ng-template>?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case to use template variable. Inside the `ng-template` use `*ngIf` to conditionally show few divs or buttons. `*ngIf` inside `ng-template` gets condition when to show those few divs or buttons via template variable `let-` which you have to supply.

Comment: Thanks!! Then I suppose this should be the best way to implement this scenario